# Policy on advertising programming languages

Tags: discussion, self-promotion

What should the official policy be for advertising one's own programming language. It is natural to want to talk about your creation, and sometimes this could be beneficial. For example, discussing different new features in a language and why they were chosen could give others some ideas. Likewise, it may just naturally come up while asking a question when extra details are required to understand the problem.

However, I do feel that there needs to be a line drawn as blatant advertising is off topic.

Comment: Doesn't existing SE rules cover our needs here?

Comment: Relevant Help Center page: [How to not be a spammer](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)

Answer (score 15):

## We can create a single megathread in meta for this purpose

Code golf already has a [list of languages created by CGCC users](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6918/what-programming-languages-have-been-created-by-cgcc-users). We could do a similar thing.

Advantages:

- Avoids cluttering the site with lots of posts
- A convenient list of new language releases
- You need a little bit of rep to participate in meta so it avoids "drive by" posts by people who just want to promote their language but not contribute

### You can also advertize/ask for feedback in chat

In moderation. We may make a separate chat room for this purpose. Rules can be agreed upon later.

Comment: If the list already exists there, what would the benefit be of recreating the list here? Would the requirements for posting be different, for example?

Comment: Well the other site is for languages created by CGCC users while people on this this site are not nececairly CGCC users. If this site should be on only 1 site it should be this one not CGCC

Comment: I get that, but do you consider that enough reason to argue in favour of data duplication? The list should do something just (even a tiny bit) different enough to warrant that.

Comment: I assume most languages here would be practlangs while most of the languages on code golf are esolangs

Comment: If CGCC has the requirement to be an esolang while PLDI would have no such requirement, that's already a pretty big distinction. But that's not a requirement there.

Answer (score 10):

## If it's relevant, disclose affiliation

I agree with mousetail's answer but just want to add this. We're all language developers, so it *will* naturally come up in the course of answering questions. Someone will ask about a neat type system feature that I happen to have implemented in language X last year. So if your language truly is relevant to an answer and makes the answer you're writing better, then you should be allowed to discuss it there, provided that you disclose your affiliation with the language.

This is consistent with Stack Overflow's policy on advertising your own libraries. If it improves an answer to mention a library you wrote, you can do so but you have to disclose that you wrote it.

Comment: Yes, the way I've done it so far is to say "here's how we did it in [the compiler I worked on]". The affiliation is clear, and it's expressed as a war story rather than an advertisement.

Comment: Relevant Help Center page: [How to not be a spammer](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)

Answer (score 3):

An *occasional* and *limited* series of open-ended "how do you do *X* in the language you're working on", on the main site, might be worthwhile as essentially a lightning rod to draw those sorts of answers to. Answers to any other questions that provided no insight outside of demonstrating a language would be deleted, as would raw advertising.

These probably aren't going to be the most brilliant questions or answers, but they may surface interesting elements of language design that wouldn't come up elsewhere.

The main reason for having them would be to redirect that energy away from all the other questions, where I fear it's going to find its outlet otherwise. People are very enthusiastic and eager to find justification why their bare demonstration really is relevant this time, and without somewhere to exert that it will bleed onto the rest of the site.

I suggest main-site rather than meta because it provides reinforcement in the form of voting that meta posts can't, and I suggest an occasional series rather than one big question so that it's not a one-and-done situation where the energy has nowhere to go afterwards and we're back to where we started.

Answer (score 1):

If it the post or added information *only* exists to advertise, we have a name for that:Spam. Only information that makes it easier to answer the question should be added (as a general rule).